# Temporary Phone Protection

Tags: substitute-tool, phone

I recently purchased a phone which is very new on the market. So new, it doesn't have any fitted cases for it yet.

What could i used as a temporary case or bumper to protect the edges and back of the phone?

So far i have been using a cloth bag, but i want access to the phone without removing the protective cover.

I have seen a [balloon used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M92jVTQ31ec), but it doesn't offer much protection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a phone case, another user suggested Sugru, but I'd like to suggest [Oogoo](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Make-Your-Own-Sugru-Substitute/) (similar compound, just easier to procure and you get way more for less) for making a phone case. There are Oogoo variants which use bleach or glycerine, along with acrylic paint instead of cornstarch.

My suggestion for doing that:

1. Wrap the phone in plastic wrap or painter's/masking tape or a combo of both.
2. Either find a container to place the Oogoo/Sugru into and then press the phone into that (however, the container will be mold and will shape your case). OR shape the Oogoo around the phone, which would allow you to shape around the buttons.

For a screen protector, you could buy the material and cut your own, see [this tutorial.](http://greylustergirl.com/make-your-own-invisible-shield-tutorial/)

Comment: I have found three different and equally interesting ways of making Oogoo variants with store bought silicone caulking: [the originial] http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Make-Your-Own-Sugru-Substitute/, [using bleach instead of cornstarch]http://blowgun.lefora.com/reply/28102573/SiliCones#reply-28102573, and [using glycerine (see the update near the bottom for the relevant info)]http://www.myheap.com/casting-molding/my-heap-mold-book/chapter-8-silicone-caulk-molds.html.

Answer (score 4):

For a bumper: Depending on the phone, you could probably use thick rubber bands, layered, if necessary.

For the screen/back glass: Wrap the phone in plastic wrap. It's not durable, but it's cheap, and you'll be able to use your touch screen through it. Also, it will scratch and bunch up before an offending object has a chance to scratch your screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own bumper with self-hardening rubber. I don't want to advertise the stuff, but this is one of their examples of things to do with it.

edit; the stuff is called Sugru, but there are others out there.